# how to read all the files in a s3 folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, node-streams

The s3 folder contains large number of files(eg 1 million file), each file contains only one json record compressed with gz format.
how to read all data/files one by one.

we have tried

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var LineStream = require('byline').LineStream;
    var params = {
        Bucket: 'xxxx',
        params: 'xxxxx'
    };

    s3.headObject(params, function (err, data) {
            
        var stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
        stream.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('Served by Amazon S3: ' + data);
        });

    });
```

any other approach is also fine

thanks in advance
Sundar

Comment: Your code would need to obtain a list of all the objects in the bucket and would then need to loop through that list to access each object individually. Rather than doing this in node, it sounds like your data could be suitable for **Amazon Athena**, which can run queries across multiple data files (although 1 million files is a lot!).

Comment: thanks for your comment . do they have any api to fetch the objects with limits, it is causing memory issues for > 1 millions files

Comment: Amazon Athena is an AWS service -- you 'call' the service much like making a request to a database. It does not run within your own code and therefore does not consume memory. I would actually recommend that you find a way to store the data that does not involve a million files, such as sending data to Amazon Kinesis Firehose that can store multiple records in a single file based on size or time. However, that advice is probably out-of-scope for this Question.